# updating a database when clicking on a button

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I have a button here:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">add me</button>
```

I tried to use AJAX; in my database I have a `sp_status` ( in my `$UserData` which is an array). I wanted to change the user `sp_status` in database with id of `$UserData['sp_id']` from 5 value to 0.
Here is the code I try to do this with it:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn").click(function(){
        alert("PROBLEM IS HERE!");  
        $.ajax({
        url: "update.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {uid: $UserData['sp_id']}, //this sends the user-id to php as a post variable, in php it can be accessed as $_POST['uid']
        success: function(data){
            data = JSON.parse(data);
        }
    });
});
}); 
</script>
```

The `$UserData` array has `sp_id` as identifier of the user.
Inside of `update.php` in same folder I wrote this code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['uid'])){
    $query = mysql("UPDATE `signup_participant` SET sp_status = 0 WHERE sp_id = ".$_POST['uid']));
    $results = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    echo json_encode($results);
}
```

There are two main problems I face with. First when I move `alert("PROBLEM IS HERE!");`one line down, and click, nothing happens.
The other problem is about `update.php`. I copy and paste `UPDATE`signup_participant`SET sp_status = 0 WHERE sp_id =10`   (static value of 10) and everything works fine in console of phpMyadmin.
I read a lot of questions here on stack, but no one helps.
Can anyone fix this?
**EDIT:**
As friends said, I change my code to this ( the AJAX part):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $(".btn").click(function(){
        alert('Hello');
        $.ajax({
        url: "update.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {uid: "<?php echo $UserData['sp_id'];?>"}  
        success: function(data){
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

The weird thing is that the popup alert is not shown anymore. Is there any ideas?

Comment: I'm surprised this works at all since the button class doesn't match the eventhandler `class="btn btn-primary"` -  `$(".button").click(function()`

Comment: Well you can either change `$(".button").click` to `$(".btn").click` or add `button` to the class attribute `class="button btn btn-primary"` I haven't looked at anything else but that's the first error I noticed.

Comment: I fix that in the question. Thanks

Comment: @AliBahrami please check the code and let me know

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you have to mistakes:

The first one is "$UserData['sp_id']" which you called in a Javascript code, it's not clear what do you mean from this variable or where did it come from, if it's a value of an Html element then it should be:

```
data: {uid: $('#sp_id').val();},
```

And if it's a Php variable it would be:

```
data: {uid: <?php $UserData['sp_id']; ?>},
```

The next mistake is in the Php server code:

```
$query = mysql("UPDATE `signup_participant` SET sp_status = 0 WHERE sp_id = ".$_POST['uid']));
$results = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
```

Those two commands are separated, the first one is for updating database and the second one for showing results from it and they must be like follow:

```
$query = "UPDATE `signup_participant` SET sp_status = 0 WHERE sp_id = ".$_POST['uid'];
mysql_query($query);

$query   = "SELECT * from `signup_participant` WHERE sp_id = ".$_POST['uid'];
$select  = mysql_query($query);
$results = mysql_fetch_assoc($select);
```

Comment: I don't get it. Where should I add $('#sp_id').val();  ?

Comment: It should be instead of $UserData['sp_id'], but as I said it depends on where is that value or variable is located, I gave an example if it's a value saved in an Html element then you should use that but if it's not then you have to use another, so if you can attach the whole code in your question it will be easier to know where it came from.

Comment: It's an array read from a database and stored inside of UserData

Comment: so you just need to add Php quotes as others mentioned so it would be data: {uid: <?php echo $UserData['sp_id']; ?>},

Comment: No response from any javascript stuff. what happened?

Comment: This seems weird to me. I comment the line you said, and alert popup comes back. but when I uncomment it, alert is not working